# How to get rid of encrypted swap?

Tags: encryption, swap

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04, including a encrypted root and swap partition. I'd like to get rid of the encrypted swap partition (not just of the encryption for it, but of the whole swap partition). I commented the swap partition out in /etc/fstab, but on system boot I am still asked for the password to the swap partition -- it seems like I need to disable the mounting of the swap partition by the crypt wrapper or whatever it may be called. Can someone please tell me how to do this?

I have tried commeting out the swap partition in `/etc/crypttab` by using a "#" as the first character in the relevant line. Still getting asked for the swap password on boot. Isn't "#" a comment in `/etc/crypttab`, or is there even more I have to do?

Comment: I would just delete the whole partition using `gparted`. But I have to admit I have no experience with encrypted swap and how swap is mounted in general.

Answer (score 1):

The cryptsetup configuration for boot time is stored in /etc/crypttab you will need to either remove the reference to the partition here or add the noauto option to it.